# Increasing Site/Page Width using CSS on Squarespace Site

Tags: css, squarespace

I've got a Squarespace website & I'm trying to increase my site width on the SKYE template so the images & content only have a small bit of padding around. [Here is the link](https://calliope-mayflower-kg3s.squarespace.com/) to the site - password123. I've tried this but no luck:

```css
#page { max-width: 1300px }
```

I'd like the space between the nav & main content closed up too but I'm struggling with that aswell. Sorry I'm not an expert at all (obviously) any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using CSS, inserted via [the CSS Editor](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545567-Using-the-CSS-Editor), to override the default style. The following CSS will decrease the space between the header and body (the `.site-header` bit) and will decrease the space between the body and the edges of the browser (the `.responsive-padding` bits).

```
.site-header {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.responsive-padding--right {
  padding-right: 30px !important;
}
.responsive-padding--left {
  padding-left: 30px !important;
}
```

As an aside, you can still share a link to your site with others (even for sites in trial mode) but setting [your site visibility](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002088548-Publishing-or-hiding-your-site#toc-site-visibility-options) to "Password Protected" and then providing that view-only password when you provide a link. You can always change the password later if you don't want people to be able to view it going forward.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works! The only thing that's not responding is the top padding for the space between the main content & nav?

Comment: Alright. That's a good example where including a link is always best, because they solutions can be tested for your site specifically. Edit your original question to include a link to the site and the view-only password as mentioned at the end of my answer. Then we'll take another look. Otherwise, adding `!important` to the `.site-header` rules may be all you need. Don't forget to upvote and/or accept answers (assuming we eventually get it right).

Comment: Ah sorry! I've changed up the image and now it's not working again. I've put the link to the site in. The blocks below are also a different width! would it be possible to change the page content width by referencing something else?